# Report Designer Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am very new to Pentaho Report Designer. I have to add my own custom attributes and styles for a report.

As for example :
I have following attributes for my page header : **family** , **font-size** etc , there I want to add my custom attribute for e.g **wrap** etc.

All layout properties are used in layout.xml and style.xml file in report.prpt file. My question is: how can I add my user-defined attribute and style to my own report.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you want to use report designer without the built in layouts in pentaho.

Try to make a report by creating a fresh new file. just under the 'File' option, you can see the new file icon. Click that to create a new file and drag 'n' drop items from the left side pane to add components like text , number or graphical fields to report.  You can customize these components by clicking on it once and modifying its properties shown on right side.